# Why a series resistor on the output of an op amp would add a zero

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, bode-plot, pole-zeroplot

[Capacitance on the output of an op amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329917/capacitance-on-the-output-of-an-op-amp)

I was looking at this post and I totally understand except the answer said that the series resistance at the output of the op amp is creating a pole and a zero. I am thinking pole is something that would attenuate the gain at 20dB/dec and zero is something increasing the gain by 20dB/dec. But here I cannot see that there is a zero being created. Shouldn't adding a capacitance always add a pole?

Also, doesn't zero means there is some frequency at which the output = 0? I am always confused of shouldn't this be a negative infinity in the gain of the bode plot since log(0) = -infinite?

Comment: In the circuit that you refer to, there is a pole but no zero. The pole is given by the inverse of the time constant involving \$C_{10}\$ determined when the stimulus, \$V_{in}\$ is zeroed. So, in the given circuit, the pole should be close to \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{C_{10}(R_{20}||R_{19})}\$. There would be a zero if the author had included the equivalent series resistance (ESR) of capacitor \$C_{10}\$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a transconductance amplifier output stage where you connect the series resistor and output cap.

[image]

If you draw the bode plot for magnitude at the Vout node, it will look like the following

[image]

So, clearly there is a pole and zero. The pole was always there even without Rseries. Addition of the Rseries changes the pole frequency and adds a zero.

Consider the transfer function
H1(s) = (1+s/wz)
The magnitude goes to zero only at s = -wz. In the bode plot, we deal the case where s = jw and for real frequencies w, the magnitude does not become 0. For eg., in the case where w = wz, magnitude is not 0 as shown below.
|H1(w)| = mag(1 + j) = sqrt(2)

Comment: Thank you so much! How does H1 goes to zero at zero frequency? Shouldn't H1 = (1-0/wp) which equals 1 at zero ferquency?

Comment: I have updated the last few statements as they were ambiguous. I think it will be clear now.